# SonarQube Java plugin 3.7 analysis error

Tags: sonarqube

Iv'e recently upgraded to SonarQube 5.2 (and Java plugin 3.7) and I am getting the following error during analysis of my project.

I've removed the class file name, but it's a non-static, private inner class.

The analysis works with Java plugin versions 3.5 an 3.6.  It only fails against 3.7

Can anyone help? I'm happy to share the source/bytecode privately.

```
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to analyze .class file (removed)
at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.notifyBytecodeVisitors(BytecodeScanner.java:82)
at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.scanClasses(BytecodeScanner.java:57)
at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.scan(BytecodeScanner.java:48)
at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanBytecode(JavaSquid.java:144)
at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:124)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:90)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:258)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:253)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:76)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 is not a valid line for a file
at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:148)
at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.checkValid(DefaultInputFile.java:213)
at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newPointer(DefaultInputFile.java:208)
at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.selectLine(DefaultInputFile.java:243)
at org.sonar.batch.issue.DeprecatedIssueBuilderWrapper.line(DeprecatedIssueBuilderWrapper.java:59)
at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.addIssue(SonarComponents.java:196)
at org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.DefaultBytecodeContext.reportIssue(DefaultBytecodeContext.java:59)
at org.sonar.java.checks.UnusedPrivateMethodCheck.visitMethod(UnusedPrivateMethodCheck.java:74)
at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeVisitorNotifier.callVisitMethod(BytecodeVisitorNotifier.java:68)
at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeVisitorNotifier.callVisitMethodAndFieldAndEdge(BytecodeVisitorNotifier.java:49)
at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeVisitorNotifier.notifyVisitors(BytecodeVisitorNotifier.java:42)
at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.notifyBytecodeVisitors(BytecodeScanner.java:80)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regression was introduced in sonar-java-plugin version 3.7, it is going to be fixed in version 3.8.
Related ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1360

Comment: You can either exclude the file from the analysis using sonar.exclusions property or disable UnusedPrivateMethod rule until 3.8 will be released.

Comment: I replace the newest lib 3.7 with the previous one 3.6; Just JAR replacement.

Comment: There is going to be a bugfix release of the sonar java plugin 3.7.1.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/rHLYkHOHUUs