# Getting error "Line must be null or greater than zero (got 0)" during a sonar build using jacoco

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube5.1, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have upgraded my sonar java plugin to 3.7. We use inbuilt jacoco plugin to do the code coverage. We use the maven target org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent and sonar:sonar to get a sonar build triggered from jenkins job. However post the upgrade i am getting the below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line must be null or greater than zero (got 0)
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at org.sonar.api.issue.internal.DefaultIssue.setLine(DefaultIssue.java:251)
    at org.sonar.core.issue.DefaultIssueBuilder.build(DefaultIssueBuilder.java:127)
    at org.sonar.core.issue.DefaultIssueBuilder.build(DefaultIssueBuilder.java:34)
    at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.addIssue(SonarComponents.java:207)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.DefaultBytecodeContext.reportIssue(DefaultBytecodeContext.java:59)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.UnusedPrivateMethodCheck.visitMethod(UnusedPrivateMethodCheck.java:74)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeVisitorNotifier.callVisitMethod(BytecodeVisitorNotifier.java:68)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeVisitorNotifier.callVisitMethodAndFieldAndEdge(BytecodeVisitorNotifier.java:49)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeVisitorNotifier.notifyVisitors(BytecodeVisitorNotifier.java:42)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.notifyBytecodeVisitors(BytecodeScanner.java:80)
    ... 57 more
```

Below is the plugins details installed with my SonarQube version 5.1.2:

- Java 3.7
- LDAP 1.3
- Git 1
- SVN 1
- Cobertura 1.6.3

We are not using cobertura. Instead using inbuilt jacoco as mentioned above.

We are using sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1.

Comment: Could you please provide the stacktrace? You might be facing this issue: [sonarqube-java-plugin-3-7-analysis-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521753/sonarqube-java-plugin-3-7-analysis-error/)

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question. Please verify. It looks like a problem that you are suggesting and we will have to wait for an update to 3.8. However just verify it once.

Comment: Yes, this is the same issue.

Comment: There is going to be a bugfix release of the sonar java plugin 3.7.1.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/rHLYkHOHUUs

Comment: I see the ticked is closed. When can we get the 3.7.1 version available for our update?

Comment: The bugfix release is under vote, you can officially get it as soon as it get released. You can find the release candidate on the vote thread.

Comment: Hey Massimo.. The release looks 2 days delayed https://jira.sonarsource.com/projects/SONARJAVA/versions/12836 . Would you have any idea when we can expect the release?