# Sonar errors wehn using Lombok @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)

Tags: sonarqube, lombok

If I use the Lombok @Setting annotation on a field with a value of PRIVATE

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Notification implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private String id;
    private long userId;
    private Event event;

    private long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();


    public Notification(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }    

}
```

The Sonar Maven plugin gives the following error:

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project mio-events: Unable to analyze .class file tv/nativ/mio/event/model/Notification: 0 is not a valid line for a file -> [Help 1]
```

Changing the @Setting value to public fixes the issue, as does removing @Setting altogether and adding a manual private setter for the field.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Could you please provide the stacktrace? I think you are facing this issue: [sonarqube-java-plugin-3-7-analysis-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521753/sonarqube-java-plugin-3-7-analysis-error/)

Comment: There is going to be a bugfix release of the sonar java plugin 3.7.1.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/rHLYkHOHUUs

Answer (score 0):

Sonar doesn't really support Lombok: [Feature request for lombok like tools](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1761)

Prior to running sonar you should delombok the source and use the generated sources for analysis. Information about this is on the page: [Delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html).  If you are using maven there's an example of using this technique here: [Example Pom](https://github.com/awhitford/lombok.maven/blob/master/test-maven-lombok/pom.xml)